# Does nonexpansive property in H-norm imply nonexpansive in 2-norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Suppose $\|f(x) - f(y)\|_H \le \|x - y\|_H$. In other words, $f$ is nonexpansive in the norm with respect to positive definite H: $\|z\|_H = z^T H z$.

Can we then say something along these lines:
$$\|f(x) - f(y)\|_2 \le K \|x - y\|_2,$$
where $K$ is a constant that depends on $H$?

Comment: Hint: use the bounds $\lambda_{min}(H)I\le H\le \lambda_{max}(H)I$ (inequalities in the sense of positive-definiteness).

Comment: But you cannot achieve $K \le 1$.